# Different color for different data labels

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I have 3 dataseries which comes from an array.

For each dataseries, I have to use the same color.

I used the property of

```
colors: ['#0000FF', '#0066FF', '#00CCFF']
Result - It is combining these colors with different dataseries
```

For 1st dataseries, I need '#0000FF'

For 2nd dataseries, I need '#0066FF'

For 3rd dataseries, I need '#00CCFF'

Here's my code below

```
for($i=1;$i<=$getCurrentMonth;$i++){

    $month = date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 10));

    if(isset($elementDetails[$i])){

        foreach($elementDetails[$i] as $value1){
            $dataDetails = '';
            for($j=1;$j<$i;$j++){
                $monthname = date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $j, 10));
                $dataDetails .= "{name:'".$monthname."',y: 0},";

            }
            foreach($value1 as $key => $value){
                $seriesDetails .= "{ name: '".$key."',data: [".$dataDetails."{name:'".$month."',y: ".$value."}],stack: '".$key."'},";
                //echo $key;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

For each dataseries, I need a specific color.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
colors: ['#0000FF', '#0066FF', '#00CCFF'],
xAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: <?php echo $getCurrentMonth-1;?>,
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    crosshair: true

},
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
        text: '',
    }
},

chart: {
    type: 'column'
},

tooltip: {
    shared: true
},
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0.1,
    }
},



series: $seriesDetails;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set color for each series by `color` property as below:

```
series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 95.6, 54.4],
        color:'#0000FF'
    },
    {
        data: [194.1, 95.6, 54.4,129.2, 144.0, 176.0,29.9],
        color:'#0066FF'
    }]
```

Working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/o2j1yd7z/2/